# Is there a way to save the Angular2 generated site as a static website

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular

I am looking for something that will take the angular 2 generated site and export it as a static web page with the html, css (or scss), and js files all exported separately. Some file export that is like the export feature from codepen where you get separate files in a directory.

If there is does it export all the html files that the Angular site generates?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you using webpack? Seems like a textbook use case.

Comment: Im not trying to download a project thats Angular ready. I am trying to export the html, js, and css that is generated from a  running angular 2 application. kinda like copying the code from the inspector tab on most browsers.

I want the static site downloaded if that makes sense.

Comment: I want to do this too to build prototypes of enhancements  that I can share with developers. I am a UX designer. Did you find a solution?